# How can I get the position or index of each checkbox on my page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I’m trying to get the index of the selected checkboxes on the page.  I’ve seen lots of examples that get the index of each newly added element to an array but I want to get the index of the checkbox’s position on the page.  I’ve been trying the code below:

```
      $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
      var selectedItems = $("input[name='selectedCourses']:checked");

        if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++)
                alert("Selected Text: " + selectedItems.eq(i).val() + " Selected Index: " + selectedItems[i].valueOf() + selectedItems.index(i).val());



     };


  });
```

I’d like to do something like this inside my loop:

```
 var positionOfCheckedBoc= selectedItems.index(i).val());
```

I’ve been able to do something like this:

```
 $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
         var checked = [];


         $("input[name='selectedCourses']:checked").each(function (i) {

             checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));

             alert("The index is " + i + " and the value is " + $(this).val());
         });

      });
```

But the index is from 0 to the number of items selected not their index or position on the page.

Please help me to get position of the selected item.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all checkboxes not only the checked ones

```
 $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
         var checked = [];


     $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) {
         if(this.checked){
             checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
             alert("The index is " + i + " and the value is " + $(this).val());
         }
         });

      });
```

Wroking **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ43M/2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.  Admit's idea worked nicely.  Thanks again for all the quick responses and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and its works,i think this is well enough to help u

```
   $("#saveBtn").on("click",function(){
        var index = 0;
     $('.selectedCourses').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                alert(index);
            }
            index++;
        });
    });
```

here the output made from ur code : http://jsfiddle.net/bvUND/64/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bvUND/65/)

You can just loop around the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
    var collection = $('body *');
    var i = $(this);
    var index = collection.index(i);
    alert("Index of item on page is :"+index);
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/99/
It'll get you the index of current input among all the elements in the body. Is this you want? You can modify it to get the position.

Answer (score 0):

### Redefine your matched set of elements

The index of an element is relative to its position in a matched set of elements.

In your example, your matched set is input elements with name "selectedCourses" that are checked. Yet, you imply that you want its index or position on *the page*, but relative to what?

- All inputs with name "selectedCourses" whether checked or not?
- All inputs regardless of name?
- All form elements even if not input elements?
- All DOM nodes?

**Expand your query and use logic to get index of desired elements in larger set**

This example assumes you want the index of named, checked inputs relative to all inputs on the page:

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {
    var checked = [];
    $("input").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).attr("name") == "selectedCourses") {
            checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
            alert("The index is " + i + " and the value is " + $(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```